# Add Node.js to Dotnet Docker Container

Tags: .net, node.js, docker, containers, docker-for-windows

I am running a Dockerfile and it is created successfully.  Unfortunately upon creation I get the error

> "InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the create-react-app server was listening for requests. The error output was: 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,".

I have looked up the error:

> 'npm is not recognized as an internal or external command."  The answers say to append 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\' to the PATH variable.  I can't seem to achieve this in my docker file.

Comment: Can you please share your Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a dotnetcore based docker image that can run on Linux, it may be easier to add node, or it may be included already.

For example, this one has both

https://github.com/emerald-squad/dotnet-nodejs

For all of the dotnet core images check

https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core